# confidence interval for threshod selection

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Can we use confidence interval to select a threshold value? Suppose I have 1000 samples of temperature variable. Can I use confidence interval to set a threshold value?

Comment: Why do you want to set a threshold?

Comment: It is for a condition. If it is less than threshold value I will execute another logic based on the threshold value

Comment: OK. For what quantity do you have a confidence interval?

Comment: temperature value.

Comment: Hm. Do you mean that you have a *prediction* interval for a *future* temperature value? [There is a difference.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info) Or do you really have a CI for mean temperatures or similar?

Comment: I read that confidence interval is used to tell the range of the true parameter value. But can it be applied to set a threshold a value too?. Let's say, I have temperature variable of sample size `n`. It is read from a device. If the value exceeds or goes  below a threshold value then the device fails. Samples are  collected when the device is running without failure. For this scenario,can I use confidence interval to get the UCB and LCB ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a possibility to apply a threshold $\tau$ to a tail of the confidence interval underlying distribution. Normally, some significance level $\alpha$ is used to specify the likely ranges of the true underlying parameter (such as for example the mean $\mu$). From your sample, you obtain an estimate $\hat{\mu}$ for which you can calculate the confidence interval pertaining to $\mu$.

You can choose an $\alpha$ as required for your application at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a scenario similar to this ," Let's say, I have temperature variable of sample size `n`. It is read from a device. If the value exceeds or goes  below a threshold value then the device fails. Samples are  recorded when the device is running without failure.For this scenario,can I use confidence interval to get the UCB and LCB using confidence interval? "